# Windows commandprompt-like screen buffer on terminal? (i.e. horizontal scrolling)

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I really like the way I can change word-wrap in the windows terminal from scaling with window to fixed-width. This way I don't need a large window to have "properly" formatted text (almost all the time, exception is when a text line is longer than my configured width).

[image: Command Prompt Properties]

It's not in the terminal settings and I've tried all sorts of commands I could find in the gnome-terminal, like `tput`, `shopt -u checkwinsize`, `export COLUMNS=500`, `stty cols 500`, etc.... But nothing works.

**Could anyone tell me if this is possible in the default gnome-terminal or if any of the other linux-terminals has this feature?**

---

Windows (desired behaviour, notice the horizontal scrollbar):

[image]
[image]
[image]

Ubuntu gnome-terminal:

[image]
[image]

(with `setterm -linewrap off`)

[image]
[image]

---

## I'm just using Spring Boot as an example here

Comment: Could you give an example of why you need this? Ideally, post a screenshot of the gnome-terminal behaving in the way you don't want. I don't really  understand what you need here.

Comment: I prefer things that were originally one line of text to be on a single line in the terminal. And scrolling or resizing the window when I want to see what's outside the window bounds.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an auxiliary viewer application, such as `less` for this functionality.

See [why GNOME Terminal rejected this idea](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=769440). Basically: this is not how terminals have worked for decades, and you can't really change such basics without breaking gazillions of things.